# What is the syntax for smoothing an embedded image with CSS?

Tags: css, image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

If I want to embed an image with smoothing I might do something like this:

```
package
{
    public class EmbeddedImages
    {
        [Embed(source="/assets/image1.png", smoothing="true")]
        public static const Image1:Class;
    }
}
```

However, if I have a bunch of buttons with different icons, I want to control which icon to display using CSS, like this:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

s|Button.image1
{
    icon: Embed('/assets/image1.png');
}
```

I want the icon to be smooth. So what is the syntax for adding smoothing when embedding with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a project to test on, but see the [`smoothingQuality` style of `Image`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html). This obviously won't work if the button uses `BitmapImage` to display the icon since the style is only available for Image. Odds are, it does use BitmapImage, though.

```
s|Button.image1
{
    icon: Embed('/assets/image1.png');
    smoothingQuality: "high";
}
```

Again, I have no way to test this so that is a complete shot in the dark. Worth a try, though

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I tried `smoothingQuality: "high";` but it did not work. I forgot to mention this is a Mobile project, and the button SkinClass I'm using inherits from spark.skins.mobile.supportClasses.ButtonSkinBase. The icon is actually of type flash.display.Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a mobile project, then the Button icon is a [BitmapImage](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/spark/src/spark/primitives/BitmapImage.as) and you could try setting its members

```
smooth = true;
smoothingQuality = BitmapSmoothingQuality.BEST;
```

or maybe do that via CSS:

```
s|ButtonImage {
    smoothingQuality: "best";
}
```